# (Co)completions?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any (perhaps small) category. Is there a (co)complete category $\mathcal{C}'$ and an inclusion $\mathcal{C}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{C}'$ which is universal among (co)complete categories containing $\mathcal{C}$? Perhaps something akin to the Yoneda embedding into the category of presheaves over $\mathcal{C}$ is the obvious choice? If not perhaps some other explanation can be given.

Comment: Justin, there is a very similar question and discussion taking place at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55859/universal-cocompletion-without-leaving-our-universe You might also look at the nLab article: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion Your surmise is basically correct. 

Comment: See Kashiwara-Schapira, Categories and Sheaves. This question is discussed in first chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yoneda $\mathcal{C}\to Psh(\mathcal{C})$ is initial among pairs (D,F) consisting of a cocomplete category $D$ and a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to D$.  That is, it's the initial object of the comma category $\mathcal{C}\downarrow_{Cat} CoComp$, where $CoComp$ is the category of cocomplete categories with colimit preserving functors between them (technically to form this comma category, we would want to form the comma category of the inclusions of both $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{CoComp}$ into $Cat$, but, hey, what's an abuse of notation between friends?).

For this reason, we call the category $Psh(\mathcal{C})$ the free cocompletion of $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: I should note that the notion of smallness doesn't play any role in the definition.  Smallness only affects whether or not the category $Psh(\mathcal{C})$ exists.

Comment: You may or may not believe that Psh(C) exists for large C. But it will not be the free cocompletion unless C is small. The free cocompletion is the category of *small* presheaves on C. 

A presheaf is small if it is a (small) colimit of representables; equivalently, if it is the left Kan extension of its restriction to some small full subcategory. 

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I was assuming that it didn't exist so I didn't have to talk about the situation where we have an annoying relative size difference.  