# Reference request: colimits of locally presentable categories

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

Consider the 2-category of locally presentable categories, cocontinuous functors, and natural transformations.  I believe that this 2-category is 2-cocomplete in the sense of containing all small 2-colimits.  One proof is outlined in Mike Shulman's answer to Martin Brandenburg's question [2-colimits in the category of cocomplete categories](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64978/2-colimits-in-the-category-of-cocomplete-categories) from a couple years ago.  In my paper with Alex Chirvasitu ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3104)), we claim (with a sketch of a proof) that the following works: (i) every cocontinuous functor between presentable categories has a right adjoint, which is continuous and commutes with sufficiently-filtered colimits, and every functor of this type has a left adjoint; (ii) take the diagram whose colimit you want to compute, and consider the corresponding diagram in the category of locally presentable categories, right adjoints, and natural transformations; it suffices to compute the limit of that diagram; (iii) compute the limit of that diagram in the 2-category of all categories, and check that the limit is presentable, and that the functors involved in the limit are continuous and commute with sufficiently filtered colimits.

My question is simply a reference request: is there a paper in the published literature that provides a careful proof that the 2-category of locally presentable categories, cocontinuous functors, and natural transformations is 2-cocomplete?  I'd rather cite this fact in my current project than reproduce the above argument, and I don't want to cite a paper (even my own) that only provides a "sketch of proof", if the fact is one I plan to rely on later.

The claim is not in the standard reference by [Adamek and Rosicky](http://books.google.com/books/about/Locally_Presentable_and_Accessible_Categ.html?id=iXh6rOd7of0C).  The closest there is the fact that the 2-category of accessible categories and functors that commute with sufficiently filtered colimits is 2-complete (and in fact 2-limits can be computed in Cat).

Comment: What is a presentable category ? And what is a cocontinuous functor ? I don't understand (i). If you mean a colimit-preserving functor between locally presentable categories, indeed it has a right adjoint by the dual of the Special Adjoint Functor theorem (take the opposite categories and apply SAFT). And an accessible limit-preserving functor between locally presentable categories is always a right adjoint indeed. This is explained in the book you mention.

Comment: And also a right adjoint between locally presentable categories is always accessible.

Comment: Philippe: "cocontinuous" means "preserves colimits".  I believe "presentable" is hipster-speak for "locally presentable".

Comment: The dual statement for right adjoints does appear in LPAC, as exercise 2.l.

Comment: (Is there any reason to prefer "locally presentable"? What would a "globally presentable" category be? I think the hipsters have a point...)

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell this is also not proven in the "Handbook of Categorical Algebra" which is the other big reference for such things. It *is* proven in Higher Topos Theory but that's overkill (I imagine if you wanted a proof that worked only in the ordinary categorical case you could set \infty = 1 throughout). I'm speaking of HTT Cor. 5.5.3.4 and Thm 5.5.3.18. (Note that homotopy limits in the infty-category of infty-categories agree with 2-limits in the 2-category of categories when everything in sight is an ordinary category)

Comment: @DylanWilson: Thanks, I'll check those out!  It is overkill, of course, to use HTT.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: Sorry, I tend to drop the word "locally" from "locally presentable", and might have missed a spot. If it helps, I'm not the only one to do this --- Lurie also drops the word "locally". There's nothing I can tell particularly "locally" about presentability of a category; I mean, the original meaning was that every object can be presented as a colimit of elements from some set of not-too-large objects. But you could reparse the meaning as "the category can be presented as the cocompletion of a colimit sketch". As Tom Leinster says, (co)continuous = preserves (co)limits.

Comment: @DylanWilson: Also, if you want to leave your comment as an answer, I'll probably accept it, unless someone digs up another non-overkill reference.  My next place to look was Handbook of Categorical Algebra, but I won't be with my copy until January.

Comment: @DylanWilson Me too, I would like to know what could be a globally presentable category.

Comment: Since it came up, let me mention that a very important property some objects $x$ in a category $C$ have is that the representable functor $C(x,-)$ commutes with $\kappa$-filtered colimits for some cardinal $\kappa$ (meaning colimits of diagrams in which every collection of strictly fewer than $\kappa$ arrows can be coconed). In $C = \mathrm{Top}$, with $\kappa = \aleph_0$, these are the compact topological spaces, so some call the general notion "$\kappa$-compact". When $C$ is a variety of algebras, these are the objects with a presentation shorter than $\kappa$, or something like that, so ...

Comment: ... some authors call the general notion "$\kappa$-presentable". It is a theorem that every object in a "(locally) presentable category" has this property for some $\kappa$, so if you say "presentable = $\kappa$-presentable for some $\kappa$", then the category is "locally presentable" in the sense that every object is presentable. But a better word might be that the category "consists of presentable objects". Anyway, I don't like overloading words when there's ambiguity; I call the notion "$\kappa$-little".

Comment: And, of course, it makes perfect sense to ask whether a given category is "little" or "compact" or "presentable" or whatever word you want in the 2-category of categories.  Maybe that's what a "globally presentable category" should be?

Comment: @TomLeinster: Is "hipster" hipster-speak for "young'uns"?

Comment: Hi Theo.  Here's an argument for retaining "locally".  Let's stick to *finite* presentability.  As you know, there's a notion of what it means for an object of a category to be finitely presentable.  In particular, you can apply this to objects of CAT.  So, this gives a notion of finite presentability for categories.  But this is not at all the same as *local* finite presentability of a category.  (Ironically, it's exactly when you're thinking higher-categorically that the terminological distinction becomes important!)

Comment: Hmm, searching around, I see you and Mike Shulman had a chat about this same issue a couple of years ago: see the comments on  http://mathoverflow.net/a/66835/586 .  I thought Todd Trimble had written about it somewhere too, but I can't find it; my faint memory was that he'd explained why "locally" is an appropriate word.

Comment: @TomLeinster I understand now: with the hipster terminology, a presentable category is not necessarily presentable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I believe there *is* a canonical reference for this fact: Greg Bird's 1984 thesis *Limits in 2-Categories of Locally Presentable Categories*. Although apparently unpublished, Google Scholar lists 20 citations to it. According to [this post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/5928/match=greg+bird+thesis) by Steve Lack to the categories mailing list, Bird proves that the 2-category of locally presentable categories, left adjoint functors, and all natural transformations has all [flexible 2-limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flexible+limit) and all flexible 2-colimits. This includes all bi(co)limits.

I don't know the history, but I gather that Bird's thesis work was in fact closely related to the very development of the notion of a flexible 2-limit: these are the strict 2-limits whose weights are such that they don't don't actually demand anything too strict, the "homotopically meaningful" strict 2-limits. Lack [later showed](https://eudml.org/doc/232481) that in fact they are the cofibrant objects in an appropriate 2-model structure on the 2-category of weights.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a copy of Bird's thesis online. **Update:** Ross Street has now made it available again [(link)](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/BirdPhD.pdf); see comment below.

Comment: I contacted Ross, and he has kindly agreed to put a scanned copy of Bird's thesis back up again, at least for a while. (And presumably permanently, if Bird can be reached and approves; he is no longer in mathematics.)

Comment: Thanks, Todd! I was starting to reach out to folks in Australia (who were very helpful!) but you beat me to the source! Thanks to Ross Street. And of course, to Greg Bird.